# store multiple values for the same field in a form

Tags: php

```
Firstname *
<input class="input100" type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter Your First Name ">


 foreach($_POST['name'] as $value)  
 {$_SESSION['name'] = array($value);}
```

I have the option to input multiple names before submitting the form. 
i need to save all the name entered in an array so as to later move them to the database.What should i do?

Comment: save in json format

Comment: OR save as comma separated string

Comment: `$_SESSION['name'][] = $value;`

Comment: Save the looping through: `$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];` unless there are already existing values you need to keep

Comment: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" this is the error I keep getting

Comment: "OR save as comma separated string – Dinesh Ghule " how do i do this??

Comment: how do you post the data ? can i see the form ? or do you use ajax ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following php code:-

```
<?php 

// $nameInputDataArray will contain the array of names from name[] input fields.
$nameInputDataArray = isset($_POST['name'])? $_POST['name']:array();


foreach ($nameInputDataArray as $name){
    // now you can access the names one by one.
    echo $name;
}
// or all the names can be returned as , separated string using implode()
echo  implode ( "," , $nameInputDataArray );

?>
```

Comment: still getting this error:"Invalid argument supplied for foreach() "